# CSS selector for node with at least N children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select nodes that have at least N children using CSS. How?

The purpose is to apply color bands ("guidelines") in a tree, but only if there are six or more nodes below the parent.

The JS, JQuery and server-side scripting suggestions I got are somewhat problematic because the children are most loaded dynamically using Ajax calls. I'd have to hack the code that injects the children to be able to e.g. add a class to those parents that have 6+ children. That's why I wanted to ask if there is a pure CSS way to do it, before I made the effort with code. I might just settle for banding regardless of child count - not as neat but fair enough.

Comment: That would require look-ahead, and I'm pretty sure CSS doesn't do look-ahead in any form.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a jQuery if-statement that will count the nodes then add a class to apply your desired styles.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WarrenBee/YeJyy/5

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var nodeCount = $('.node').length;

    if( nodeCount > 6 ) {
        $('.node').addClass('nodeStyles');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well css3 has some child selectors that could do the job.

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ li {
    ... some style
}
```

For this solution the credit goes to André Luís who discovered it. Of course it doesn't work on  the parent element, because that's css4 and not supported yet. But you could style all the `li` tags if there are 6, or just the first `li` tag.

In combination with before pseudo element you could make a parent styling visually.
The ul get's `position:relative`.
Then you could fake styling on parent with a pseudo element:

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(6):before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:400px;
  height:20px;
  background:green
}
```

The css selector nth-last-child is not supported in every browser, but for Internet Explorer you could use javascript or IE7.js. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you're entering code, be sure to highlight it and use the "Code Sample" button at the top of the text editor. It looks like a set of curly braces `{}`. Also, you can use backticks ( ` ) to indicate pieces of code or object references in your text. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) out for more information. :)

Comment: The level 4 selector to use would be pretty simple: `! > li:first-child:nth-last-child(6)` Of course it bears repeating that that doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly possible because CSS does not provide any method for selecting parents based on the properties of the children.

For a strictly CSS solution, I would add a class to the parent element, and style that class.  Instead of manually adding the class where necessary, you could handle it pro grammatically on the server-side.

You can certainly do this using JavaScript, and the process will be simplified by the many available JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Or, if using some kind of server-side language, use that to add the CSS class. No extra libraries required!

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir - Naturally - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

[CSS have no parent selectors of any kinds yet](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

You can, however, use JavaScript to do so. The following is a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjGK4/)):

HTML

```
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('ul').each(function(){
        if($(this).children('li').length >= 6){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
        }
    });
});
```